# installing NODEJS on remote AWS instance of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.1

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, amazon-web-services

I have been trying to install NODEJS on remote AWS instance of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.1

I had read some of the posts here and been on the node js website

I have tried t

```js
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
```

but then get the error

error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (Permission denied)

i even get this error if i run

```js
sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
```

I have also tried to change the permissions on that file but then it still doesnt install

Can someone suggest a better way / correct way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try `rm` the rpm.lock file?

Comment: Why did't you accept any of the answer ?

Answer (score 25):

You just don't have permissions to install things. It doesn't matter you are running *curl* with *sudo*, because what really needs superuser permissions is the *bash* session inside which you run the script.

So, this would work.

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
```

Comment: Duh, it's failing the permission on the bash, not on the curl. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 1):

At least on one of our ESXi RedHat virtual machines the easiest way I know to install nodejs is:

```
    yum install epel-release
    yum install nodejs
```

Let yum do all the heavy lifting :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be running as a non root user.
Before running your actual curl command, run

```
sudo su
```

Then run (without sudo, since you are now running as root user)

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
```